# C# : more efficiency coding in delegate/event subscribe in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I'm to subscribe to event, i'm coding like that: (in visual studio 2010)

#### 1. I Write down like following code:

```
this.Loaded +=
```

#### 2. I Press tab key.

#### 3. A IDE fill a below code automatic:

```
this.Loaded+=new RoutedEventHandler(someClass_Loaded);
```

#### 4. But the method someClass was not exist yet. so I write a method like following code:

```
private void someClass_Loaded()
{
}
```

#### 5. But signiture of someClass was not defined properly yet. so I set cursor on the delegate, "RoutedEventHandler".

#### 6. I press F12. and then IDE showing me a define of the RoutedEventHandler.

```
namespace System.Windows
{
    [...]public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
}
```

#### 7. copy a arguments of the RoutedEventHandler.

#### 8. I paste it to the method someClass_Loaded

```
private void someClass_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Is it best coding practice?

ps. When I subscribe a event by anonymous method, I do like this.

Comment: Ummm, "best coding practice" doesn't refer to literally how you type in your code. Do it in whatever way feels comfortable for you is all I can say.

Comment: No, "do what the IDE seems to want me to do even if I don't understand it" is not a best coding practice.

Comment: thanks for BoltClock and NateC-K. you guys are alright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. press tab key.

Try doing this twice. Not only will Visual Studio expand the new event handler assignment, it will also create a stub method in the class that has the correct name and proper signature.

Comment: @mjk6026 Your comment made my day. So funny!